# Designate a speficied day of 20 days later

Tags: org-mode, calendar

Strike "C-u C-c ." to insert the current datetime,

```
  <2020-03-25 Wed 09:56>
```

How could I designate a accurate day of 20 days later,
Currently, I  invoke "Shift+ right-arrow" step-move the the day of 20 days later.

Is it possible to insert a future day with a method of "+20d"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `org-time-stamp` from the library `org.el` supports the increment/decrement day feature out of the box.  In an `org-mode` buffer, type `C-c .` or `C-u C-c .` and then just type `+20` and press the enter/return key.  The function `org-time-stamp` uses the function `org-read-date` -- to read the various options for `org-read-date`, type `M-x describe-function` aka `C-h f`.

---

Here is an alternative method that lets the user control the format of the time/date that gets inserted -- the format is hard-coded.  The function `org-read-date` from the library `org.el` supports the increment/decrement day feature out of the box.  The doc-strings for `org-read-date` and `format-time-string` are lengthy, so go ahead and type `M-x describe-function` aka `C-h f` to read about the various options.  To try out this example using `my-org-insert-date` below, type `M-x my-org-insert-date` and then just type `+20` and press the enter key.  This will work in any mode; i.e., there is no requirement that the buffer be in `org-mode` in order to use this example.

```lisp
(require 'org)

(defun my-org-insert-date ()
"Insert a date at point using `org-read-date' with its optional argument
of TO-TIME so that the user can customize the date format more easily."
(interactive)
  (let ((time (org-read-date nil 'to-time nil "Date:  ")))
    (insert (format-time-string "<%F %a %I:%M>" time))))
```